# Pushing numbers from a text file into a link list

Tags: c, list, while-loop, singly-linked-list, fgetc

I am trying to push numbers from a text file into a linked list which might have multiple digit numbers in multiple lines. My output is a mess, only printing -47 multiple times. My main doubts are how to read a 2 digit number from the file, although my current code is not even reading any number.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linklist
{
     int data;
     struct linklist *addr;
}ll;

void push(ll **h,int val);
void display(ll **h);


void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("re.txt","r");
    char c;
    ll *head=NULL;

    while(c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' ' || c=='\n')
        {
            continue;
        } 
        else
        {
            int temp=c-'0';
            printf("Temp = %d",temp);
            push(&head,temp);
        }
    }
    printf("check");
    display(&head);
    fclose(fp);
}

void push(ll **h,int val)
{

    if(*h==NULL)
    {
        ll *temp=(ll*)malloc(sizeof(ll));
        temp->data=val;
        temp->addr=NULL;
        *h=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        ll *current = *h;
        while(current->addr!=NULL)
            current=current->addr;
        current->addr=(ll*)malloc(sizeof(ll));
        current->addr->data=val;
        current->addr->addr=NULL;      
    }
}

void display(ll **h)
{
    ll *current=*h;
    while(current->addr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",current->data);
        current=current->addr;
    }
}
```

Edit:

The re.txt file looks like this:

```
4
2 1 8 19
6 11 50 89
21 22 47
25 35
```

Comment: Don't use `fgets` which only read characters but use `fscanf`. Also [edit] and show the first 3-4 lines of `re.txt`.

Comment: So your list should contain the numbers 4,2,1,8,19,6, etc. ? Please confirm.

Comment: @Jabberwocky when using fscanf, what do I do when I encounter a newline or does fscanf take care of that?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes that is the list

Comment: Side note: best avoid a name such a `l` or `ll`. My first thought was "what are those elevens doing". Worse for an r-value. You shouldn't have to peer at code or mistake a variable for a number.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks I'll keep that in mind from next time

Comment: Note that `while(c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF)` is missing a critical set of parentheses. It should be `while( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)`

Comment: OT: regarding; `void main()`  Per the C standard, there are only two(2) valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`.  Some non-conforming compilers (like visual studio) will allow invalid code statements, but you should not exploit their short comings

Comment: regarding: `while( (c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)` and `char c;`   The function: `fgetc()` returns a `int` not a `char`   Also, a `char` will not properly compare to `EOF`, so depending on if a `char` is `signed` or not the `EOF` might never be recognized

Comment: OT:  regarding: `fp=fopen("re.txt","r");`  a function call (like `fopen()`) can fail.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL)  then call `perror( "fopen failed" )` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr` so the user is informed of the problem.  Generally, this is a unrecoverable error, so clean up then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `ll *temp=(ll*)malloc(sizeof(ll));`  The function `malloc()` can fail.  Therefore: 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest: `ll *temp = malloc(sizeof(ll));  if( ! II ) { perror( "malloc failed" ); //cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the posted code results in a massive memory leak (actually several memory leaks, one for each number input) because the code fails to pass each memory allocation pointer to `free()` before exiting

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix any warning messages.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  Then use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) to check for memory leaks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fscanf` which does the work for you.

You want this:

```
int main()
{
  FILE* fp;
  fp = fopen("re.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
     printf("Can't open file\n");
     return 1;
  }
  char c;
  ll* head = NULL;
  int temp;

  while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp) != EOF)
  {
    printf("Temp = %d\n", temp);
    push(&head, temp);
  }
  printf("check");
  display(&head);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

There is still room for improvement though.

Comment: `scanf(fp, "%d", &temp) == 1` is a better idiomatic test.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the condition in the while loop

```
while(c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
```

is incorrect. It is equivalent to the following condition

```
while( c = ( fgetc(fp) != EOF ) )
```

So if `fgetc( fp )` is not equal to `EOF`  then the expression `fgetc( fp ) != EOF` evaluates to `1` and the variable `c` will get this value `1`.

The while loop shall look at least like

```
while( ( c =  fgetc(fp) ) != EOF  )
```

And the variable `c` should have the type `int`.

```
int c;
```

Otherwise the loop can be infinite because the type `char` can behave as the type `unsigned char` (depending on an option of the compiler) and the variable `c` will be never equal to the signed value of `EOF`.

However in any case this loop is incorrect because the function `fgetc` also reads white space characters while you need to read whole numbers.

So change the loop like

```
int temp;

while ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &temp ) == 1 )
{
    push( &head, temp );
}
```

Also the function `push` can look simpler. And it can signal to the caller whether the memory for the new node was allocated successfully Otherwise the function can invoke undefined behavior in the case when the memory allocation fails. For example

```
int push( ll **h, int val )
{
    ll *temp = malloc( sizeof( ll ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        temp->data = val;
        temp->addr = NULL;

        while ( *h != NULL ) h = &( *h )->addr;

        *h = temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function `display` can invoke undefined behavior when the passed pointer to the head node is equal to `NULL`. And the function will output nothing if the list contains only one node.

The function can be declared the following way

```
void display( ll **h )
{
    for ( ll *current = *h; current != NULL; current = current->addr )
    {
        printf("%d\t",current->data);
    }
}
```